# Unknown race condition: onError firing sometimes - Youtube Iframe API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api, preact

[Here is a fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/7f2qk5ed/1/)

Rerunning the fiddle multiple times you will see the following message  `Yay we got the error 150` appears only sometimes. I would expect the error to appear every time.

I load the YT API immediately `componentDidMount`

```
function loadYTIframeAPI() {
  var tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}
```

I instantiate the player once the ajax request has completed

```
new window.YT.Player(`player${id}`, {
  events: {
    onReady: e => {
      console.log("onReady", e.data, e.target.a.id);
      this.setState({ readyData: "ready" });
      if (index === 0) {
        console.log("play");
        e.target.playVideo();
      }
    },
    onError: e => {
      // this should fire every time but only fires sometimes 
      console.log("onError", e.data, id);
      this.setState({ errorData: e.data.toString() });
    }
  }
});
```

I render the iframe video with

```
<iframe id="player512347" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AmtOraYA4p0?enablejsapi=1&origin=https://fiddle.jshell.net&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything obviously wrong with your code. Hopefully Google engineers spot this as promised on the support page.

Comment: david, maybe is because in your jsfiddle sample you're using a non-existing `videoId`? - I tested your code with a working video and I couldn't get the error you mention (*and I played the same video more than 6 times*) - tested with this `videoId` = *`XKCUpiClJK8`*. Have you tried with other `videoId`s?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave that's kind of the point - I won't know if the videoId is valid until I get an error. I could check using their API or other means but this should work ...

Comment: @david_adler I tested again your jsfiddle more than 5 times non-consecutive and I could get the custom error every time. How many times you get these error in - let's say - 10 tries?. The workaround you describe at the end about query whether the `videoId` is valid (or you can also make a request to this URL: `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=<VIDEO_ID>` and check it results). If you consider that these options aren't valid for your purposes, I suggest you post your question in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). Sorry for not be more helpful. Good luck.

Comment: It could be that the bug was fixed - the fiddle does seem to be fine, as you say.